# Meteor @import css: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, mime-types

I keep seeing this message in my console, although my stylesheet seems to be loading fine (they weren't originally, seems they have to be in the client folder, is that correct?). I'm on Meteor 1.4.2.3.

My folder structure is

```
> client
    > styles
         - formStyles.css
         - tableStyles.css
    - main.css
    - main.html
    - main.jsx
```

In my `main.css` file I have the following code:

```
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "styles/tableStyles.css";
@import "styles/formStyles.css";
span{
    color: black;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

When I load the page, I get the following warnings in the Chrome Dev Tools Console:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html: "http://localhost:3000/styles/formStyles.css".
>
> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html: "http://localhost:3000/styles/tableStyles.css".

Originally, my `styles` folder was outside the `client` folder (under `ui`) and no styles were applied, but now the styles do get applied but I'd rather not see warnings in my app...

I also tried using absolute paths like this `@import "{}/styles/formStyles.css";` but it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: I don't think native css does imports. If you are thinking SASS, then you should use the meteor package fourseven:scss to do what you want

Comment: It does since CSS 3 (the URL above gets imported fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css files are placed under `client` folder, that means you do not have to `import` anything. Those files will be concatenated automatically for you. You should read this guide: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories